# How do I implement Undo in a coloring app, which uses RenderTexture

Tags: objective-c, undo

My app uses `RenderTexture` `begin()`, `visit()`, `end()` methods to draw on a canvas(a render texture). Now, how do I implement Undo feature for 1-5-steps.

In my game update loop,
Calculate touch and prev `touchlocations` in the node space, and the distance between them, and draw the line on the canvas by visiting the brush node.

I did have a look at slipster216' reply on : [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/alpha-blending-problem-with-layer-rendertexture-and-sprites/)

But, this approach will probably mean, writing again from the start, as it needs custom stroke class.

Ideas  :

1. Save state of render texture someHOW ?
2. Save images on `touchended` and read them on undo on to the sprite, someHOW ?
3. Keep '5' render texture in the memory, to be replaced while un-do, but heavy on memory ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a temporary buffer of 5 sprites. Each time the user draws something, store it first in the temporary buffer like a queue.
At the 6th draw, send the first element to the permanent render texture. For undo, simply delete the queue.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll paste the code, if anybody needs it. Just put in a comment here.